# How can I find an LED bulb that works with my light's high/low settings?

Tags: lighting

I purchased 2 different brands of the required LED lights for my oven hood; the lights are dimmable. However, the oven hood has only a toggle switch for High and Low; there is no visible difference between these 2 settings with the LED bulbs.

Should I just keep trying different brands of the same bulbs?

Comment: Make/model of hood?

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Comment: Are you sure your hood doesn't require a three-way bulb? Please revise to provide more detail.

Comment: Hello, it's a BROAN-NUTONEGlacier BCSD 30 in. and in the instructions require 2 LED M16 GU10 7 watt max bulbs of which  I bought 2 different brands since thought I had faulty bulbs as it did not address high/low issue

Comment: There was no mention in the instructions regarding using a 3 way bulb

Answer (score 2):

I think your range hood was made for incandescent lights. Mine was, and when I  changed to LED, it seemed like both switch positions gave bright. The reason has to do with the way it dims, or tries to dim. It switches to an alternate path with a rectifier diode, so half the voltage is clipped off. I found that I can get a dimmed light by first going to the bright position then quickly going to dim. Sometimes it takes a few tries. It always works for me. I use dim for kitchen night  light. It might not work for the kind of LED bulbs you have.

Answer (score 1):

There is no signficant difference between brands for this issue.  If it's any consolation, LED's use so little power compared to incandescents that dimming doesn't save much at all.  If it's the aesthetics, there's not much to do other than pick how bright you want your one choice to be.